# Adding javascript code to joomla (view) default.php file does not work

Tags: jquery, joomla, jqplot

I want to use (jquery) jqplot in my Joomla (3.3) view file - default.php, pls see code below.

However, when calling this file the frontpage does not show a chart and the console shows the error 'Uncaught typeError: Undefined is not a function' at the line of $(document).ready() function.

I suspect I embed the  $(document).ready() function in the wrong way in the default.php file(?), but I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Joomla default.php view file:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

//add jqplot libraries
//JHtml::_('jquery.framework); //I tried this before - same console error
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);

JHTML::script('jquery.jqplot.min.js');
$document->addStyleSheet('media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css');
JHTML::script('jquery.jqplot.min.css');
JHTML::script('jqplot.barRenderer.min.js');
JHTML::script('jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js');
JHTML::script('jqplot.pointLabels.min.js');
JHTML::script('jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.js');
JHTML::script('weqlib.js');
?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ //here the error console displays an error
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]); //copied from example at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php

    }); //$(document).ready
</script>
</head>

<!--<h1><?php echo $this->msg; ?></h1>-->
<body>
  <div id="chart1" style="width:600px; height:250px;"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining paths to files, you should always start with `JUri::root` which is the root of your Joomla site. For example:

```
JHtml::_('script',  JUri::root() . 'templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/weqlib.js' );
```

Of course change the path to where ever you have the files located.

On a side note, you can use the following to import your Stylesheet aswell rather that using `$document->addStylesheet()`:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet',  JUri::root() . 'media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css' );
```

As for your jQuery function, after importing the js files correctly as mentioned above, your code should work, however if it doesn't, try running jQuery in noConflict mode by changing this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);
```

to this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

and once done change you custom script to this which uses `jQuery` as the alias:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Lodder, you made my day, thnx! I followed all your suggestions and the frontpages now shows the graph. Still, the console displays the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token at jquery.jqplot.min.css:1". You understand why? (I never edited the jquery.jqplot.min.css file)

Comment: Hey, glad this solved your issue. The error you're getting is something to do with the plugin itself. I had a look on Google and found this (read the very last comment): https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/how_can_i_display_the_chart_in_mobile_app_using_fusioncharts

Comment: Sorry, **plugin** was the wrong use of wording. I meant it's to do with the jqplot library. I'm not too sure about the details of this error as I have never used jqplot

Comment: @Joppo - I've made a small change to the code when importing CSS and JS files using `JHtml`. Please take a look